# Unique phrase for customer

Tags: ios, swift, function, swiftui, switch-statement

I have function where I'm creating one of the cases randomly, but I want when I start the app It will only generate the message once and when I will open it again it will be the same but not different. Any idea how should I make it ?

Here is code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListOfMessages: View {
    @State private var isDetailViewPressed = false
    
    let uniqueCustomer: String
    let topColor: Color
    let bottomColor: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isDetailViewPressed.toggle()
        }) {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [topColor, bottomColor], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                    .cornerRadius(13)
                    .frame(height: 120)
                    .padding(10)
                    .opacity(0.8)
                
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text(uniqueCustomer)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .bold()
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                            .padding(30)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    Image(systemName: "envelope")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .padding(.leading, 260)
                        .padding(.top, -30)
                }.padding(.top, -30)
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isDetailViewPressed) {
            DestinationView(uniqueCustomer: uniqueCustomer)
        }
    }
}

struct DestinationView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    let uniqueCustomer: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: . topLeading) {
            
            Image("space")
                .resizable()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            Button(action: {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding(.leading, 30)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
            })

            Text(uniqueCustomer)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .font(.system(size: 40))
                .bold()
                .padding(.top, 70)
                .padding(.leading, 30)
            
            Text(makeRandomPhrase(randomNumber: Int.random(in: 0...2))) //Here need to create a phrase only once
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.system(size: 30))
                .bold()
                .padding(.top, 120)
                .padding(.leading, 30)
                .frame(width: 350)
        }
    }
    
    func makeRandomPhrase(randomNumber: Int) -> String {
        
        let makePhrase: String
        var myName = "Mário"
        
        switch randomNumber {
        case 0: makePhrase = "Hey \(myName) I'm so glad that I had seen you out. Could we go on football match this evening? \n\nRegards,\n\(uniqueCustomer)"
        case 1: makePhrase = "Hello \(myName) how are you? I haven't seen you for a long time. We should meet somewhere in town if you are down. \n\nAll the best,\n\(uniqueCustomer)"
        case 2: makePhrase = "Eyo \(myName) what will we do today?"
        default: makePhrase = "Hey \(myName) I'm so glad to see you here."
        }
        
        
        return makePhrase 
    }
}
```

I though about creating a json file where I will save the phrase and then take the phrase out. This was not working. I was expecting that the phrase will generate only once for each customer.

Answer (score 0):

What you posted here won't work even if you save the phrase to a JSON file because your view calls `makeRandomPhrase(_:)` every time it's rendered - so even if you have already saved a phrase, it won't be used.

Instead, you might want to change that function to something like `retrieveRandomPhrase(:_)`, which first tries to load the phrase from your JSON file and then, if there's no phrase saved for this user yet, generates a new one and saves it.

That said, I don't see anything here that saves it to the JSON file either, so the code you posted might be missing something. If so, please update your post.

As a side note, if you're trying to save a small amount of user-specific information to the device then I would recommend using [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) rather than creating files yourself.